# Disable/detect Windows 7 Snipping Tool?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

My company makes Flash tools for use in online market research, and often get requests for additional security for promotional material, product videos/images etc, so that they cannot be captured.

We are already using various different methods for this (e.g. clearing clipboard at regular intervals, forcing users to hold space down while viewing an image) but it has just come to our attention that these methods can be easily circumvented by using the Windows 7 Snipping tool.

Ideally we would block the use of this tool entirely - although even just being able to detect that this is in use, and then hiding the media would be better than nothing.

Are there any methods (JS, AS or otherwise) that enable you to disable or detect this? Or am I wasting time trying to achieve something that is impossible?

Comment: If I were taking a market research questionnaire and found it randomly clearing my clipboard, I can assure you that I would never deal with that company again.

Comment: Also, you’re wasting your time. Thankfully, it is totally impossible to prevent users from taking a screenshot on their own computer.

Comment: Couldn't you detect when the browser loses focus (or a mouse_out on the body or something) and then hide the flash movie? And then show it again when the focus returns (or mouse_over on the body).

Comment: Also, please direct your customers to me. I would like to sell them a magic rock that keeps tigers away.

Comment: My magic rock has successfully kept all tigers away for many years now.  It also works on elephants.  However I can still view source or view cache on my PC and firebug does a great job of showing me those ajax requests.

Comment: @Daniel It's actually pretty common! It's a p.i.t.a when you leave a tab open and forget about it though.. Also, magic rocks are our top seller ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are wasting your time trying to achieve something impossible.  Even if it were somehow possible to detect this particular tool, there are many other ways of capturing the contents of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a coding question, it's a copyright question.

From technical point of view it is impossible to prevent someone from taking a screenshot or copying stuff you put on the internet. You can put any system in place and in the most extreme scenario I can still take a photo of the PC screen with my mobile phone.

If you want to truly protect your images and videos, add a copyright note to each of them and then prosecute everyone who violates the copyright law.

Law is on your side, so don't afraid to use it. It's easier than inventing impossible solutions ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you can make Win32 API (for example, you run Adobe AIR, or if you have an ActiveX), then you could use the msdrm API: [DRMRegisterProtectedWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

That will prevent the snipping tools, as well as the print screen from working. As people above suggested, this isn't a bullet proof protection, but it is a step. If you target occasional users (vs. determined hackers) that will help.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent snipping tool usage, simply black out the picture when the mouse is not over the picture. This will stop the snipping tool... unless your users know autohotkey